# Joining Tables to Update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, left-join

Can I do this to update a row?  This is the first time I am using a `LEFT JOIN` with an `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE comments AS r

LEFT JOIN items AS i 
        ON i.items_id = r.item_id
LEFT JOIN master_cat AS c
        ON c.cat_id = i.items_id  
SET r.good = r.good + 1 
WHERE i.item = '{$item}' AND c.category = '{$cat}' AND r.review = '{$review}';
```

It doesn't throw an error, but it says 0 rows affected even though I have confirmed my variables are ok with right data. (Even if I hard code the data).

**Edit**:  I have tried inner join as well, and does not work either.

**Edit 2**: This is actually what I am trying to do, I have these two queires and they work fine.  I am trying to simplify code to one.  Can this be done:

```
     // This query returns rate_id which I use as "$review_id" in the second query.

     $query = "
     SELECT r.rate_id
     FROM comments as r
     LEFT JOIN items AS i 
         ON i.items_id = r.item_id
     LEFT JOIN master_cat AS c
         ON c.cat_id = i.cat_id
     WHERE r.review = '{$review}' 
        AND i.item = '{$item}' 
        AND c.category = '{$cat}';"; 

    $query = "
    UPDATE comments 
    SET good = good + 1 
    WHERE rate_id = '{$review_id}';";
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense that your first `update` statement would affect 0 rows... but the same statement written as a `select` would return one row.

Comment: Is `rate_id` the primary key of table `comments`? Because if it isn't, I'm not at all sure that what the 2 statements do, is what one would actually want to be done.

Comment: @ypercube Yes, rate_id is primary for comments.

Comment: Is `good` by any chance `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in the `UPDATE` statement you have a mismatching join (`cat_id` with `items_id`):

```
LEFT JOIN master_cat AS c
        ON c.cat_id = i.items_id
```

while in the `SELECT` (that is working), you have the join correctly:

```
LEFT JOIN master_cat AS c
        ON c.cat_id = i.cat_id
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're outer joining to a table c, and then you have a where clause on a field in table c, you effectively have an inner join, since the where clause will not match anything if the join condition misses.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you wanting to do a `LEFT JOIN`?  You're not using any of the columns from the joined tables to update the row... so I'm assuming that the purpose of the joined tables is to limit the rows to be incremented in `comments` to only those that have a match in the associated tables.

The reason that you're getting 0 rows affected is that you've placed additional conditions for the left joined tables in your `WHERE` clause, which is essentially turning each `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Assuming that this is a simplified version of your query, and that you have other reasons for wanting to use `LEFT JOIN`, you would fix this by moving the conditions into your `ON` clauses:

```
UPDATE comments AS r
    LEFT JOIN items AS i 
        ON i.items_id = r.item_id
        AND i.item = '{$item}' 
    LEFT JOIN master_cat AS c
        ON c.cat_id = i.items_id  
        AND c.category = '{$cat}' 
SET r.good = r.good + 1 
WHERE r.review = '{$review}';
```

Comment: I need `$items` and `$cat` which are from two other tables, but have their id's in the `comments` table - so what is correct way to join? (Oh, I see your answer.. let me check)

Comment: @KickingLettuce Please see my example... be aware that since these are left joins, that every row in `comments` that matches the `WHERE` clause will be updated.

Comment: Ok, I see the issue, no , I don't want left join if that is the result.  I tested this query and it still did not update.  Like I said, I do need the three tables to be associated with each other in some way.  I need to update a row ONLY in `comments`.  But it requires $items and $cat from the other two tables to find the correct row based on id.

Comment: @KickingLettuce What you describe is what your original query was doing... or what a query using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` would do as well... If there is no single row that has matches in both `items` and `master_cat`, there is nothing to update, which appears to be what is happening.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I must be missing the concept.  As a matter of test, I changed `UPDATE comments as r` to `SELECT * FROM comments as r`,and it found no row,  Then I changed INNER JOIN back to LEFT JOIN, and it found the row I am trying to update. I am not sure what I found here... but as you say, LEFT JOIN selects everything.  I just need it to change `r.good` in the original table.

Comment: @KickingLettuce That is telling you that you have rows in `comments`, but you don't have any rows in `comments` that have matching rows in your other two tables, `items` and `master_cat`.

Comment: Ok, last try.  I have added new code:  These are two queries that work exactly as needed.  I am simply trying to simplify code down to a single query.  Can this be done?